# Why does the linking of GLSL Shaders crashes my program?

Tags: opengl, segmentation-fault, glsl, shader

I am writing a compute shader in GLSL, which did work well until I did use some implemented functions in this shader. It does still compile but now it crashes my program cause of a segmentation fault while linking. The compilation is done without any errors (or they are not printed). The compilation and linking works well for other compute shaders, too.

I tried to find some problematic lines of code in the shader and I did find some, but I do not know why they cause this crashing. So I provide a part of the code:

```
#version 430 core

//Input point cloud
struct pc_point_t{
  vec4 vertex;
  vec4 normal;
};

layout (std430, binding = 0) buffer pointCloudBuffer
{
  pc_point_t pointCloud[];
};

//global nearest neighbor stuff
int idxNN[15];
float distNN[15];
vec3 vertNN[15];
vec3 normNN[15];
#define K 4

void initNeighbors()
{
  float curDist, maxDist; //maxDist gets initalized

  for(int i = 1; i < K ; i++)
  {
    curDist = distance(currentCubePosition,pointCloud[i].vertex.xyz);
    if(curDist > maxDist)
    {
      //maxDist = curDist; //This line causes the crash.
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < K; i++)
  {
    //idxNN[i] = idxMaxNeighbor;  //This line causes the crash.
    distNN[i] = maxDist;
    //vertNN[i] = pointCloud[idxMaxNeighbor].vertex.xyz;  //This line causes the crash.
  }
}

void neighborSearch()
{
  initNeighbors();

  //do the neighbor search
  //...

  for(int i = 0; i < K; i++)
  {
    //normNN[i] = pointCloud[idxNN[i]].normal.xyz; //This line causes the crash.
  }
}

main()
{
  //do some stuff
  //...

  neighborSearch();

  //do some more stuff
  //...
}
```

Does anybody has an idea why this happens?
Please ask if you need more information.

There was no update of the graphics driver in the last week and all lines which causes the crash while using them are marked with comments.

Here is the code to compile and link the shader:

```
std::shared_ptr<QOpenGLShaderProgram> cGLSLShaderHandler::createComputeShaderProgram(const QString &computeShaderPath)
{
  auto shaderProgram = std::make_shared<QOpenGLShaderProgram>();
  bool result = true;
  //! Load and compile the compute shader
  if (!computeShaderPath.isEmpty()) {
    result = shaderProgram->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Compute,
                                                    computeShaderPath);
    if (!result) {
        qWarning() << computeShaderPath;
        qWarning() << shaderProgram->log();
    }
  }
  //! ...and finally link it to resolve any references.
  result = shaderProgram->link();

  if (!result)
    qWarning() << "Could not link shader program:" << shaderProgram->log();
  return shaderProgram;
}
```

and the backtrace of the debugger is the following:

```
0  ??
1  ??
...
14  ??
15  QOpenGLShaderProgram::link()
16  DeviceHandler::QtOpenGL::cGLSLShaderHandler::createComputeShaderProgram
... -> The rest should be irrelevant
```

the output of an address sanitizer reveals that the actual crash is in the libnvidia. So this should be a graphics card driver error.

The problem occurs on laptops using optirun and on pcs too.

Comment: Please show the code where you link the shader. Also run your program in a debugger and provide a backtrace.

Comment: I added the compiling and linking code and the backtracing follows in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shown linking crash is based on an error in the graphics card driver. It seems, that the actual problem has something to do with the static loop optimisation.

A quickfix for this problem would be to set `K` as an input uniform variable or set `K` depending on another input variable. Of course, this is not a good solution, but it is one and it can be used until nvidia fixed the bug.